# What Happened To Spore servers? Spore servers gone!

Tags: spore

I have recently been unable to log into my SPORE™ account, so I looked for help. EA said that the servers were down for newer accounts, but any accounts made before 2012 should be fine. Mine was made in the beginning of 2009, and it still does not work. What should I doo?

Answer (score 12):

According to the 2015-07-16 post, "[Spore Maintenance Notice](https://web.archive.org/web/20180216095029/http://forum.spore.com/jforum/posts/list/83392.page)" from the Official Spore Forums:

> Due to technical issues, we are taking down the Spore game servers for several days. We are working on a fix and will let you know when the servers will be up and running. You can still play Spore but creature sharing and online features will not be available during this time.

It seems as though they are still performing maintenance.

Comment: maintenance lasting a few *weeks*? O.O

Comment: Maintenance as in 'save them money' maintenance?

Comment: @DoubleDouble For a game that is as old as Spore is, I can't imagine they are dedicating that many personnel to it's care. That is of a personal opinion though. Most games this old have servers wither and die at this point (http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2014-05-12-50-ea-games-will-have-their-servers-shut-down)

Comment: @Tobel From the forum posts, I gathered that one person is now in charge of it - and if you believe the person who supposedly has contact with that person, the issue is hardware related with no money for replacement part(s), so it could be "*several months*"

Comment: Welcome to the future of DRM'ed games. Companies like EA are counting on gamers to have limited to no attention span and have forgotten about a game long before they stop maintaining the servers.